# Animating when navigating with SwitchNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im using `createSwitchNavigator` to seperate my auth flow from the rest of the app. While navigating from one context to another, is there anyway to trigger an animation? The default behaviour is to replace the screen in place which is a little bit.. unceremonious.

**An example** would be navigating to `App` from a `Login` screen via `this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")`

```
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Login: AuthStackNavigator,
    App: AppStackNavigator,
  }
);
```

If not i'd be happy to listen to how you handle this scenario. Thanks a lot.